# Owlcarousel not working properly on IE Mobile 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

The OwlCarousel slider is not switching slides automatically on the page load in IE Mobile 11, you have to press a next arrow then it starts switching automatically and stops again after a while. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update OwlCarousel to the newest version.